# How to set Client Id and Client Secret for External credential Principal from Apex

Tags: apex, connect-api, externalcredentials

I am building a Getting started page for a Managed package App to easily configure [External Credential](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_connectapi_output_external_credential.htm?q=External%20c).

I am using [ConnectApi.NamedCredentials.createExternalCredential](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_ConnectAPI_NamedCredentials_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_NamedCredentials_createExternalCredential_2) method to dynamically create External credential

however I couldn't find an option to set clientId and clientSecret for the [ExternalCredentialPrincipalInput](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_connectapi_input_external_credential_principal.htm) in the documentation.

This seems to be inconsistent because this is possible from UI.
Is there a way I can set `clientId` and `secret` programatically

Here is my sample code:

```
ConnectApi.ExternalCredentialInput externalCredentialInput = new ConnectApi.ExternalCredentialInput();

externalCredentialInput.developerName = 'Test';
externalCredentialInput.masterLabel = 'Test';
externalCredentialInput.authenticationProtocol = ConnectApi.CredentialAuthenticationProtocol.OAuth;
externalCredentialInput.authenticationProtocolVariant = ConnectApi.CredentialAuthenticationProtocolVariant.ClientCredentialsClientSecretBasic;

externalCredentialInput.principals = new List<ConnectApi.ExternalCredentialPrincipalInput>();
externalCredentialInput.parameters = new List<ConnectApi.ExternalCredentialParameterInput>();

ConnectApi.ExternalCredentialParameterInput scopeParam = new ConnectApi.ExternalCredentialParameterInput();
scopeParam.parameterName = 'Scope';
scopeParam.parameterType = ConnectApi.ExternalCredentialParameterType.AuthParameter;
scopeParam.parameterValue = '<scope value>';

ConnectApi.ExternalCredentialParameterInput authProviderUrlParam = new ConnectApi.ExternalCredentialParameterInput();
authProviderUrlParam.parameterName = 'AuthProviderUrl';
authProviderUrlParam.parameterType = ConnectApi.ExternalCredentialParameterType.AuthProviderUrl;
authProviderUrlParam.parameterValue = '<Token endpoint>';

externalCredentialInput.parameters.add(authProviderUrlParam);
externalCredentialInput.parameters.add(scopeParam);

// Populate principals to connect the external credential to permissions
ConnectApi.ExternalCredentialPrincipalInput principalOne = new ConnectApi.ExternalCredentialPrincipalInput();
principalOne.principalName = 'Developer Access';
principalOne.principalType = ConnectApi.CredentialPrincipalType.NamedPrincipal;
principalOne.sequenceNumber = 1;
// principalOne.clientId = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
// principalOne.clientSecret = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
externalCredentialInput.principals.add(principalOne);
ConnectApi.ExternalCredential createdEC = ConnectApi.NamedCredentials.createExternalCredential(externalCredentialInput);
```

Comment: related - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials_merge_fields.htm